# Get median value from array of decimals

Tags: c#, arrays, median

I've need to work out all the averages (mode, mean, median, range) from an array of numbers.

The calculator is taking input from `NumericUpDown` and adding them to a `listBox`,
The listBox items are added to a `List<Decimal>` (because it seems easier to print to label).

For each average method the list is converted to an `Array` because it seems easier to calculate.

Not going to lie, I don't even know where to begin with median...

I've copied some code form various solutions on StackOverflow and what not but none of them work because they weren't written for decimals and too be honest, I don't really understand the code.

**AddNumbers**

```
 //Add number to list and retun to 0.
    private void btnAddNums_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //Add selcted item from listbox
        listBoxNumbers.Items.Add(numUpDownAvg.Value);

        //Create new instance of listNumbers
        List<Decimal> listNumbers = new List<Decimal>();

        //for each decimal in listbox...
        foreach (Decimal listItems in listBoxNumbers.Items)
        {
            //Add to listNumbers
            listNumbers.Add(listItems);
            numUpDownAvg.Value = 0;
        }

        //iterate though list printing each item seperate by a comma
        for (int i = 0; i < listNumbers.Count; i++)
        {
            txtBoxNumbers.Text = (String.Join(",", listNumbers));

        }

        //print list to console 
        Console.WriteLine(String.Join(",", listNumbers));
    }
```

**Median**

```
    //This button prints median to results
    private void btnMedian_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        //Create new instance of listNumbers
        List<Decimal> listNumbers = new List<Decimal>();

        //for each decimal in listbox...
        foreach (Decimal listItems in listBoxNumbers.Items)
        {
            //Add to listNumbers
            listNumbers.Add(listItems);

        }

        //Convert list to array 
        decimal[] listArrayofNumbers = listNumbers.ToArray();

        Array.Sort(listArrayofNumbers);

        var n = listArrayofNumbers.Length;

        decimal median;

        var isOdd = n % 2 != 0;
        if (isOdd)
        {
            median = listArrayofNumbers[(n + 1) / 2 - 1];
        }
        else
        {
            median = Convert.ToDecimal(listArrayofNumbers[n / 2 - 1] + listArrayofNumbers[n / 2]) / 2.0d;
        }

       // Console.WriteLine(median);

    }
```

}

the error is `median = Convert.ToDecimal(listArrayofNumbers[n / 2 - 1] + listArrayofNumbers[n / 2]) / 2.0d;`

The error says **"Operator "/" cannot be used with type decimal or double "**

assuming I need to cast to decimal somewhere? Obviously Convert.ToDecimal isn't right...

TIA!

Comment: Just cast it to `double` or use `Decimal.Divide()`.

Comment: @Шах - Lol, not sure where to cast it to `double` or how to use `Decimal.Divide()`?

Comment: Scrap the call to `Convert.ToDecimal` (or use `2.0m` rather than `2.0d` -- `d` means `double`, not `decimal`)

Comment: @DaviebPrime, yo processor doesn't support 128-bit operations, so `decimal` is software support by JIT. `Decimal.Divide(a, 2)` and `a / 2m` are equal by the performance. But the second variant is shorter and better. If yo app doesn't require 128 bit calculations, it's much better to use `double` or even `float`.

Comment: There is no reason to convert a `List<>` to an array - you can do all the same things with `List` as `Array`.

Comment: @NetMage - It was because Array have .Avg and .Min and .Max which List do not, right?

Comment: LINQ includes `Enumerable.Average`, `Enumerable.Min` and `Enumerable.Max` which works with all collections that implement `IEnumerable`, which is pretty much all collections, including `List<>`.